# get permalink and append it

Tags: permalinks

I have product pages which need a button to link to the related appointment booking page. So for example I'll create a page called 'glass-product', and I want to code its template so that there's a link to a page called 'glass-product-book'.

So I need to get the permalink of the post, but then add '-book' to the URI within the link, presumably I need to add something to the current:
    `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Book Now</a>`

Anyone know what needs adding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, succinctly you could just add `'-book'` to your link, if your permalink settings result in post-name slugs:

```
<a href="<?php echo untrailingslashit( get_the_permalink() ); ?>-book/">Book Now</a>
```

However if you're not very careful, or are planning on running a site with a large number of content or with several people having access to the dashboard - you'll probably end up with broken links at some point.

The more robust solution would be to store the ID of the related appointments page in a [Custom Field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Usage) on the products page (let's call the field `product_appointment_page_id`), then retrieve the corresponding appointment page permalink in your template:

```
<?php
  $appointment_page_id = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'product_appointment_page_id', true );

  if( ! empty( $appointment_page_id ) )
    echo( '<a href="' . get_permalink( $appointment_page_id ) . '">Book Now</a>' );
?>
```

Even better still would be to implement both "products" as well as "appointments" as their own [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types), then associate them with the [Metadata API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API), as in the previous example.

Comment: Thanks Bosco - the first solution actually creates a link to 'glass-product/-book', there's only a couple dozen products  and only me on admin.

Comment: Ah, right! Luckily there's [a function to get rid of trailing slashes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/untrailingslashit). Try it now.

Comment: Not sure I get how the second option works but will give it a try. Products and appointments are already custom post types, so I will look into option 3 too. Many thanks.

Comment: Perfect - will try the other options too for thoroughness, but this is a solution. Thank you!